# Quality of the DOM element screenshot using "captureSelector" in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, jpeg, screenshot, casperjs

I'm using [casperJS](http://casperjs.org/) to try to get a screenshot of a DOM element using [captureSelector](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#captureselector), but the quality of the screenshot is really poor, but when capturing full screenshot using [capture](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#capture) it works correctly, the quality is correct.

Can anyone help me with this issue? Thanks in advanced.

**CasperJS script**

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: true,
    loadPlugins: false,
  }
});
// ***************************************************
var viewport_width = 1524;
var viewport_height = 768;
var ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"; 
var filename = "./screenshot_"+new Date().getTime() + "_" + viewport_width + "x" + viewport_height + "_desktop.jpg";
var url = "http://url-here.com";
var lang_header = "fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3";
// ***************************************************
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.log('Remote message caught: ' + msg, "error");
});
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
  this.log("Page Error: " + msg, "error");
});
casper.on('load.finished', function (status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    this.log("Failed to load page", "error");
  }
  else {
    this.log("The page has been loaded", "info");
  }
});
casper.start();
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
  this.userAgent(ua);
  this.viewport(viewport_width, viewport_height).then(function() {
    this.wait(5000, function() {
      this.waitForSelector('#dom-element-id', function() {
        this.captureSelector(filename, '#dom-element-id', { quality: 100 });
      });
    });
  });
});
casper.run();
```

Even using the quality imgOptions parameter I get really poor quality screenshots.

```
this.captureSelector(filename, '#dom-element-id', { quality: 100 });
```

**PhantomJS: version 1.9.7**

**CasperJS: version 1.0.2**

PD: I didn't put the real urls because is an internal project. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated the versions and it works now:

**PhantomJS: version 1.9.8**

**CasperJS: version 1.1.0-beta3**

Thanks for the help :)